# python 2 print get rid of empty line

Tags: format, python-2.x

In python 2 when I want to print couple number like this:

```
1
2
3
5
```

but my output can only be

```
1
2
3

5
```

my code is

```
for i in range(1,6):  
    if (i==4):
       print ''
    else:
       print i
```

so , how can i get rid of the empty line?
How can I using one line statement to get the output？

```
   for i in range(1,6):
       print i if i != 4 else pass
```

Is that working?

Answer (score 0):

How about not printing anything at all for that case:

```
>>> for i in range(1, 6):
...   if i != 4:
...     print i
... 
1
2
3
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply not do anything, which is called `pass` in python.

```
for i in range(1,6):  
    if i == 4:
       pass
    else:
       print i
```

(Note that I removed the parenthesis around your boolean expression. It's unnecessary and unpythonic.)

Or more simply:

```
for i in range(1,6):  
    if i != 4 :
       print i
```

Both will output:

```
1
2
3
5
```

If you're keen on a 1 line statement, I would do this:

```
print '\n'.join(str(x) for x in range(1,6) if x != 4)
```

Comment: How can I using one line statement to get the output？
    for i in range(1,6):
       print i if i != 4 else pass
Is that working?

Comment: print '\n'.join(str(x) for x in range(1,6) if x != 4)  is a one line statement that works well.